# Get current url hostname NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack

I have a multidomain site, I need knows if my project is running in "website1.local" or "website2.local".
I used this code to try to get the current url, but it doesn't work:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

var url = require('url');

var requrl = url.format({
   protocol: req.protocol,
   host: req.get('host'),
   pathname: req.originalUrl,
});

console.log(requrl);
```

The error returned is: **req is not defined**

How can I get the current url of my node project?

Comment: Where is request supposed to be defined?

Comment: @RaymondPeng is simple, tell me how to get the current url with Node

Comment: @RaymondPeng you  can have a look over the below answer

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

- [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href) - returns the href (URL) of the current page
- [`window.location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname) - returns the domain name of the web host
- [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) - returns the path and filename of the current page
- [`window.location.protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/protocol) - returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)

Comment: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. window object is not defined in Node js and Webpack.